# Direction of tube when measuring air flow

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, measurements

When doing pitot tube measurements, the pressure is measured in 2 places. At the wall (A), for the static pressure and against the flow (B), for dynamic pressure. Where the difference between these two is required to determine the velocity.

I recently started working in a company where pressure in the machine is measured with the flow (C). To my surprise they have a good read on the velocity in the machines.

I wonder what physical quantity is being measured, since it is not static or dynamic pressure?
Is the measurement just a 'reference value' that translates to a velocity only due to the experience of years working with these machines?

[image: Measuring tube perpendicular to flow (A), against the flow (B) and with flow (C)]

Comment: So how do your calculations look for B and C?

Comment: The pitot tube formula (as I know it) is $v^2 = 2*\Delta P / \rho$.
When both the static (A) and dynamic pressure (B) are know the delta P is the difference between the two.
How the velocity would be calculated using (C) is basically my question, so I cannot really answer that.

Comment: So work it out for B and C, Not A. How do the results differ?

Comment: We currently do not have measurements of all these quantities on the same system. I am trying to set that up to prove to my colleagues that these are not the same thing.
I am just trying to understand what physical quantity they have been measuring all this time when using (C).

Comment: So base it on the theory - many many textbooks cover pitot tubes.

Comment: Correct. But every single one of them I have been able to find use setup B.
I cannot find setup C anywhere at all, hence my question. Does anyone have any theory on that?

Comment: So analyze it and see what happens.

Comment: As I said. The experiment is still being setup.
I am trying to find some theory so I can read up on what to expect and/or explain any results I find.

Comment: As I suggested it may be more sensible to analyze it BEFORE you do the experiments. Pencil and paper are cheap, the experimentation time can be very expensive especially in wind tunnels. Spent hours with sub and supersonic at Uni running labs.

Comment: I am not sure but I suspect Setup C will measure both the dynamic and static pressures as Setup B would do. The main assumptions are that there is no flow at the entrance of the tube and the total mechanical energy is conserved. I think these assumptions are valid for Setup C too.

Comment: Are they getting good readings or just readings?  Installing it backwards would give you a negative flow reading (?), I'd expect pressure at C to be less than A.  Their method is counter to how the equation is derived.

Answer (score 0):

The C section is reading the suction. Varying between zero for no velocity to -1 atm for maximum speed which has been calibrated to their range of the experiments. The readings will rang between 1 atm for zero flow to zero atm for the calibrated max flow velocity.

Because the lab has a controlled air temperature and pressure the static pressure is constant and doesn't need measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the Pitot tube pointing downstream, there's still a streamline joining a zero-velocity location in the tube opening to a location at the full free-stream velocity, so you can still apply Bernoulli's equation to get the velocity from the pressure difference. I think with the tube this way round, I'd be somewhat worried that said streamline might have to cross from inside to outside the turbulent wake of the tube, thus traversing a region where the flow is not irrotational, and therefore Bernoulli's equation doesn't hold; but if you've observed empirically that the velocity values you get are good, I guess that's not a problem.